# How do I show Password Protected Pages to users NOT logged in?

Tags: wordpress

I know you can use `WP_Query` if the user **is** logged in to return all the posts with a status of `private`, but cannot see how to do this for a user who isn't logged in?

EG: For users who are logged in...

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'post_status=private' );
```

But, how to do for Users who are **not** logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filter [`posts_clauses`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70214/multiple-orderby-parameters-in-pre-get-posts-action/70220#70220), like:

```
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse70214_posts_clauses' );

function wpse70214_posts_clauses( $pieces )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if( !is_user_logged_in() )
        $pieces['where'] = str_replace( 
            "post_status = 'publish')", 
            "post_status = 'publish' OR $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'private') ",
            $pieces['where']
        );

    return $pieces;
}
```

Comment: Look's like a definite solution! Will try it and let you know ASAP! Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: Just a quick question. I tried to impement this code in my function.php page then call the function wpse70214_posts_clauses() in my page template, but it doesn't appear to return anything? Sorry I am not a very strong developer. Thanks for the help so far...

Comment: No, you don't have the call the function. The filter takes care of that. And better than `functions.php` is to create [your own small utility plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615).

Comment: How do I only apply the small utility plugin to a single page in wordpress? Cheers

Comment: I don't get is... is it a new question? Does this code solved your issue?

Comment: Keep getting the followig error when trying to execute the function _Warning: Missing argument 1 for clientportal_posts_clauses(), called in /home2/maxcross/public_simonjohn.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dk/page_clientportal.php on line 228 and defined in /home2/maxcross/public_simonjohn.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dk/functions.php on line 905_

Answer (score 0):

You could create a guest user, and if the current user is not logged in use code to log them in as a guest...then your query will work.

You will want to review groups and permissions when building out the solution. Also, the last thing to consider is how to present the login screen to guest users so that they can login as a real user.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for the Answer, but I am not a strong developer so wouldn't even know how to begin doing something like that... Surely there is a simpler way???